# Online Accounts + Facebook + Issue [12.10 64bits]

Tags: facebook, online-accounts

As many of us, I also having some trouble to add the Facebook Account using "Online Accounts". I used some of answers I found here, doing that step-by-step: Log in the Facebook account, access My Apps, but when I reached this one, I noticed that "Ubuntu" application simply doesn't exist, then I cannot remove it from Facebook, of course.

I was looking for the Ubuntu application in the Facebook App database, but neither there I found it.

Does anyone having the same issue?

Comment: I think you might be referring to Gwibber which is working fine for me...

Comment: Same here. That's why I switched to Pidgin and managed to integrate it into Unity Panel very well with a couple of tweaks.